# Unit Test on nodejs class with chain of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Can you please help me to write unit test for Publish method. It should cover the line mentioned left side.

The import statement 'amqplib' need to be mocked in jest.

ch.publish and conn.close, etc should be asserted

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as amqp from 'amqplib';
import { RabbitMQOptions } from '../interface';
import { RABBITMQ_OPTIONS } from '../constant';

@Injectable()
export class EmitDirectService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(RABBITMQ_OPTIONS)
    private readonly rabbitMQOptions: RabbitMQOptions[],
  ) {}

  publish(queueName: string, message: string) {
    let rabbitMQOption = this.rabbitMQOptions.filter(x => x.name == queueName);
    if (!rabbitMQOption) {
      throw Error('Connection string does not exist');
    }
    amqp
      .connect(rabbitMQOption[0].connection)
      .then(function(conn) {
        return conn
          .createChannel()
          .then(function(ch) {
            var ex = rabbitMQOption[0].exchangeName;
            var ok = ch.assertExchange(ex, rabbitMQOption[0].exchangeType, {                        // Need Test Coverage
              durable: false,
            });

            return ok.then(function() {                                                             //Need test coverage all subsequent 2 line
              ch.publish(ex, rabbitMQOption[0].key, Buffer.from(message));

              return ch.close();
            });
          })
          .finally(function() {
            conn.close();                                                                           // Need test Coverage
          });
      })
      .catch(console.warn);
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously as if a colleague of yours has asked you to test your code, and now you're asking us to do that for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is as per our client standard, all code must be unit tested. so looking for helps.