# Could not mock oracledb.getConnection() in jest unit test for nodejs typescript class that use oracledb npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, node-oracledb

This is nodejs typescript class to execute query or getConnection using oracledb npm.

I could not mock oraclebd getConnection in jest unit test.

How to write unit test for executeQuery. It shows test coverage to be done on finally block all statement.

I written unit test but

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb';
import { ORACLE_DB_OPTIONS } from '../constant';
import { OracleDBOptions } from '../interface';
import { PromInstanceCounter, PromMethodCounter } from '@digikare/nestjs-prom';

@PromInstanceCounter
@Injectable()
export class OracleDBService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(ORACLE_DB_OPTIONS)
    private readonly oracleDbOptions: OracleDBOptions[],
  ) { }

  @PromMethodCounter()
 async executeQuery(
    dbName: string,
    query: string,
    bindValue: any[] = [],
  ) {
    let localConnection: any;
    try {
      const oracleDbOption = this.oracleDbOptions.filter(
        x => x.name === dbName,
      );
      if (!oracleDbOption) {
        throw Error('Connection string does not exist');
      }
      localConnection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: oracleDbOption[0].user,
        password: oracleDbOption[0].password,
        connectString: oracleDbOption[0].connectString,
      });
      const result = await localConnection.execute(query, bindValue);
      await localConnection.close();
      return result;
    } finally {
      if (localConnection) {
        try {
          await localConnection.close();
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Error when closing the database connection: ', err);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  @PromMethodCounter()
  async getConnection(dbName: string) {
    const oracleDbOption = this.oracleDbOptions.filter(x => x.name === dbName);
    if (!oracleDbOption) {
      throw Error('Connection string does not exist');
    }

    const localConnection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: oracleDbOption[0].user,
      password: oracleDbOption[0].password,
      connectString: oracleDbOption[0].connectString,
    });

    return localConnection;
  }
}
```

Written Unit Test for getConnection() method.

```
describe('OracleDbService', () => {
  let oracleDBService: OracleDBService;

  let oracleDBOptions = [
    {
      name: 'rfdest',
      user: 'rfdest',
      password: 'rfdest',
      connectString: 'alsyntstb.ohlogistics.com:1521/syntstb',
    },
    {
      name: 'DOCGENDEV',
      user: 'DOCGENDEV',
      password: 'DocGen$dev18',
      connectString: 'alsynwebd.ohlogistics.com/synwebd_maint',
    },
  ];

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        OracleDBService,
        {
          provide: ORACLE_DB_OPTIONS,
          useValue: oracleDBOptions,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    oracleDBService = module.get<OracleDBService>(OracleDBService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(oracleDBService).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('getConnection success', () => {
    jest.fn(getConnection).mockReturnValue({
      execute: function() {},
      close: function() {},
    });
    oracleDBService.getConnection('rfdest').then(resolve => {
      expect(resolve).not.toBeNull();
    });
  });
  it('getConnection throw error', () => {
    jest.fn(getConnection).mockReturnValue({
      execute: function() {},
      close: function() {},
    });
    oracleDBService
      .getConnection('')
      .then(resolve => {
        expect(resolve).not.toBeNull();
      })
      .catch(reject => {
        expect(reject).not.toBeNull();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: First, you mention `getConnection`. Later, `executeQuery` (which isn't even a method of node-oracledb). What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: OracleDBService is a class that has 2 method executeQuery() and getConnection(). oracledb is a npm which is used to create connection and execute query. this oracledb is imported here and used in executeQuery() and getConnection() method. we need to write unit test for executeQuery() and getConnection(). I did for getConnection() of OracleDBService but test coverage is not 100%. I could not write unit test for  executeQuery() since don't know how to mock getConnection() of oracleDB npm. Please advise.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180905/how-to-stub-oracledb-with-sinon

Comment: I also recommend reading through this: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/mocking-is-a-code-smell-944a70c90a6a

Comment: It's a very important read... But this is the most relevant part: "Don’t unit test I/O. I/O is for integrations. Use integration tests, instead."

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886155/unit-test-on-nodejs-class-with-chain-of-promise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202923/discussion-between-user3497702-and-dan-mcghan).